# How do i retrieve timestamp from Firebase Realtime Database and show it on a text view as a Date

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am able to generate a timestamp and store it on Firebase Realtime Database .But unable to figure how should i retrieve it and show it in textview . I know it is retrieved as a long value and stored as a Map 
i have also created the following  in my model class but don't know what to do next.

```
private Map<String, String> timestamp;
```

Code for sending messages

```
    private void sendMessage(String sender, final String receiver, String message) {

        if (sender.equals(receiver)){
            Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this,"Message Can't be sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {

            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("sender", sender);
            hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
            hashMap.put("message", message);
            hashMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
            hashMap.put("isseen", false);


            DatabaseReference Chatreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");

            Key = Chatreference.child(ChatKey).push().getKey();
            Chatreference.child(ChatKey).child(Key).setValue(hashMap);
}
```

Code for reading messages

```
private void readMessages(String myid, String userid, String imageurl) {

    mChat = new ArrayList<>();

    Chatreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats").child(ChatKey);


    Chatreference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
            if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myid) && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                    chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender().equals(myid)) {
                chat.setMessageId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                mChat.add(chat);
                Log.d(TAG, "Child_Event_Listener_Called");
                Log.d(TAG, "msg " + chat.getMessage());
            }

            messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this, mChat, imageurl);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }


        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
            chat.setMessageId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

            mChat.remove(chat);
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });

}
```

Update Model Class

```
    public class Chat {
    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private  String message;
    private boolean isseen;
    private Map<String, String> timestamp;
    String MessageId;


    public Chat(String sender, String receiver, String message, boolean isseen, Map<String, String> timestamp) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.message = message;
        this.isseen = isseen;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public Chat() {
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return MessageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        MessageId = messageId;
    }

    public boolean isIsseen() {
        return isseen;
    }

    public void setIsseen(boolean isseen) {
        this.isseen = isseen;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Map<String, String> timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Chat){
            Chat chat=(Chat) obj;
            return this.MessageId.equals(chat.getMessageId());}
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, could you share Chat class

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir Updated Model Class

Comment: Okey, firstly timestamp is a long value not map. You have to change in Chat class

Comment: I changed timestamp to long

Comment: You should long to date string. Wherever you want to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly timestamp is a long value not map. You have to change in Chat class

```
//...
private boolean isseen;
private long timestamp;
String MessageId;
//...
```

Then you can convert timestamp to date string like this:

```
public static  String longToDateString(long timestamp, String format){
    return DateFormat.format(format,new Date(timestamp)).toString();
}
```

Using

```
String date = longToDateString(mChat.get(position).getTimestamp, "dd.MM.yyyyy");
```

or

```
String time = longToDateString(mChat.get(position).getTimestamp, "HH:mm");
```

Comment: public static String getTimeDate(long timestamp){
        try{
            DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
            Date netDate = (new Date(timestamp));
            return dateFormat.format(netDate);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return "date";
        }
    } i used this and now i can show every thing , what changes should i make make just to see time and minutes

Comment: Just one thing more i wanted to say it shows an error here cannot resolve method     format(format,new Date(timestamp))

Comment: Can not resolve method format(java.lang.String,java.util.Date)

Comment: import java.util.Date;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

Comment: Already imported  import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date; imported but stilll same

Comment: Found out my mistake Thanks bye the way

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to read a `child` in the `FirebaseDatabase`. Below is an example on how to read a child element through the `snapshot` that you will get from firebase. The model here is different, as you will have a different NoSql structure in your database.

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
  // ...
});
```

Also, the value returned from the firebase could be `long` or `String` based on the data type in which you will be storing your timestamp. It looks like it is getting sent in the form of `String`.